# Rails 5 with Adhoq gem. Unable to resolve bundler dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, bundler

OK, so I am trying to install the [Adhoq](https://github.com/esminc/adhoq) gem into my Rails 5 project.

When I add it like usual (`gem 'adhoq'`) it fails as the default dependencies are for rails 4 with a few other outdated libraries of which I have more recent versions.

I can see `gemfiles/Gemfile-rails-5.0x` exists but I have never seen this design pattern before.

I know I could fork it and manually update the dependencies but that presents a whole host of other issues and since this gemfile exists it leads me to something I currently don't know about Bundler or gems as a whole.

A glance at the Bundler docs wasn't helpful, but I will keep digging.

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: What is the exact output of the `bundle` command? Are you specifying the version Adhoc, for example `gem 'adhoq', '0.1.2'`?. 0.1.2 is compatible with Rails 5+.

Comment: yes  0.1.2 is compatible with Rails 5+ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

1. Add `gem 'adhoq', '0.1.2'` into Gemfile. (0.1.2 is latest)
2. before `bundle install` check the dependencies of other gems with `adhoq`. To check **runtime dependencies** please refer this website. https://rubygems.org/gems/adhoq.
3. Execute `bundle install`. You will not receive any errors if all runtime dependencies satisfied for the `adhoq` gem.
4. Still If you are not able to execute `bundle install` than Remove `Gemfile.lock`. and once again execute `bundle install`. Hope this will work.

**Note: To avoid step 4 you can update particular gem one by one to satisfied runtime dependencies.**

Cheers